# Why Can not I inflate a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new with android I have this MainActivity :

```
    static TableRow row;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
            text.setText("Test");
        }
    }
```

I want to add a row table for ten times and each one has a text view with `Test` word inside but I want this to be grammatically not using any ready layout because in advanced cases I may read from xml and I do no know the numbers of rows that I will need .
The layout `row` contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bahisdoktoru.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the app I do not get anything just the Hello world text (The activity_main.xml works ) but the rows and the text inside them do not show (row.xml does not work I think).
I hope you can tell me If I miss anything or If I wrote something wrong how could I show the rows that I want grammatically ?

Comment: If you wont know how many rows will you need then you supouse to use ListView and an adapter instead of inflating layouts because your approach is not optimized for larger sets of data and your app will simply freeze

Comment: You are not adding the newly inflated `View v` anywhere in your layout. You need to add a layout to your hierarchy in order to be displayed:)

Answer (score 0):

```
use below code instead of yours :-

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
                text.setText("Test");
            }
```

Comment: I use this but still same problem does not show the `row.xml`